# Why does stargazer give me a table of output for my lm regression output but not for when I use lm_robust()?

Tags: r, stargazer

When I used

`est <- lm_robust(x~y, data=df)
stargazer(est, est, type="text")`

R says "`% Error: Unrecognized object type.`"
 but prints my output properly when I don't try to use robust standard errors.

I'm just looking to find a way to organize my `lm` regression output into a simple table to include in my paper. Is there another way I can do this if not with the `stargazer` package?

Comment: check the ```texreg``` and ```xtable``` packages

Comment: [this page](https://declaredesign.org/r/estimatr/articles/regression-tables.html) shows what your options are

Comment: `stargazer(tidy(est), type = "text")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a workaround for robust standard errors and `stargazer`, as follows:

```
library("sandwich")
library("plm")
library("stargazer")

data("Produc", package = "plm")

# Regression    
model <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
             data = Produc, 
             index = c("state","year"),
             method="pooling")

# Adjust standard errors
cov1         <- vcovHC(model, type = "HC1")
robust_se    <- sqrt(diag(cov1))

# Stargazer output (with and without RSE)
stargazer(model, model, type = "text",
          se = list(NULL, robust_se))
```